# binding is not working

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I am trying to show a record of name and roll no in the form of table but I only get blank instead of the actual string stored in the object.

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void runthis(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        name per= new name();
        per.nam = "sujit";
        per.roll = 1;
        name cl = new name();
        cl.nam = "sumit";
        cl.roll = 2;
        observable.lst.Add(per);
        observable.lst.Add(cl);
        lstview.DataContext = observable.lst; 

    }

    private void add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        name cl = new name();
        cl.nam = "sumit";
        observable.lst.Add(cl);
    }

   }
public class name
{
    public string nam;
    public int roll;



}
public static class observable
{
    public static ObservableCollection<name> lst = new ObservableCollection<name>();
}
```

The xaml code is as follow

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Loaded="runthis">
    <ListView x:Name="lstview" 
  VerticalAlignment="Top"
  Margin="10,240,0,0"
  ItemsSource="{Binding}"

  BorderBrush="#19FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1"  >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding nam}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding roll}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
    <Button Content="Add" Click="add"/>
</Grid>
```

Can anyone point the fault in this code which leads to show only blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML does not support DataBinding to fields. Only properties. Change your code like this:

```
public class Name
{
    public string Nam {get;set;}
    public int Roll {get;set;}
}
```

BTW, please use proper C# naming conventions, classes and class members should be ProperCased.